# How to use select2 4.0.0 with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I am trying to use select2 4.0.0 in my angular js code. But it is not affecting the code at all.

```js
indexApp.controller('myAllyController', function($rootScope, $scope, $route, $localStorage,$routeParams, $location, $http, $window, $filter,$modal,GPlusAuthService1,$q) {
 
 /*Select 2 tool*/
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').select2();
 });
```

```html
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="aTN in allyTypeName" value="{{aTN.alliesTypeID}}">{{aTN.alliesTypeName}}></option>
</select>
```

I am using the above code....i have included css and js files inside my main file still it is not working..

Comment: Can you create plnkr for your problem?

Comment: ok but how it will run in plunkr without the server